# what is UI-binding in angularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Everywhere I read that **UI Binding** is the best feature of AngularJS. I just want to know what is this? I am a bit new in this.

Comment: the variable withing a controller reflects in the UI as soon as it updates. I think, this is UI binding.

Comment: How about going to www.angularjs.org and read about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UI Data Binding is a way to associate fields on a form with fields in a data store.  When the user changes the fields on a form, and then clicks an Update button to submit their changes, data binding causes the corresponding fields in the data store to be updated.  This also works for creating new records as well.

**See Also**
[A conceptual overview of Data Binding in Angular](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/databinding)
[An example of Data Binding in an Angular form](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms)

In the form example, note the use of `ng-model` attributes in the `input` elements of the form.  This is how Angular maps your form fields to the data store fields.

Comment: may I please ask for a bit more explanation? may with some examples...

Comment: Read the articles I linked.  If you still have specific questions, come back here and ask those.

Comment: it's cool... thanks! I will read even a  bit more on this.

Answer (score 2):

@RobertHarvey's answer is correct.

Just to contribute, here's the absolute simplest explanation I can muster:

### UI Data Binding

- **UI**: The user interface where the user views and updates information.
- **Data**: an object that holds information for your program.
- **Binding** The act of linking the data to your ui, so that:

  - When the UI is updated, the binding updates your Data.
  - When the Data is updated, the binding updates your UI.

### Example

#### UI

A view with user input and display:

```
<input ng-model="userInput"/>
<p>You've entered: {{userInput}}</p>
```

#### Data

In our Controller, we'll have a JavaScript object like this:

$scope.userInput = 'Input something here';

#### Binding

The attribute `ng-model` and the `{{userInput}}` clause are directives that handle the binding for you.

In this case, `ng-model` sets up both reading `$scope.userInput` from the input control, *and* writing `$scope.userInput` to the input control. and the `{{userInput}}` statement sets up writing `$scope.userInput` to the view.

### Summary in the case of Angular

So in angular your bindings are generally set up by directives. Directives are the attributes you'll see in you view, things like `ng-repeat`, `ng-click`, `ng-show`, etc. They are set up by creating a `$watch` on properties of `$scope` to watch for changes to your data, and also by setting up DOM events to watch for changes to the inputs or DOM.

If you wanted to get more in depth about how the binding works, I wrote a [blog entry on $watch, $apply and $digest](http://www.benlesh.com/2013/08/angularjs-watch-digest-and-apply-oh-my.html) and how they work that goes over the deeper backend, along with an [entry on $compile](http://www.benlesh.com/2013/08/angular-compile-how-it-works-how-to-use.html) and what it does to set up bindings to the DOM via directives.

Comment: I found it more meaningful to understand.

Comment: Added some additional detail in the case of Angular.

Answer (score 2):

In UI programming when you have a UI component, like a text box you might want to connect it to a Javascript object, so that when the value in the box changes the object's value changes as well.

This is useful for complex UIs where you have multiple representation of the same data. Having a Javascript object in that case makes the synchronization much easier.

In those cases you need a way to synchronize the updates between the text box (UI component) and the object. Some frameworks provide easy, declarative way for you to specify that those properties are bound together, this is UI data binding that AngularJS is referring to. In some libraries, like Backbone you have to bind the objects together, which is a very repetitive process.

Because you are new in the subject, I will suggest that you look into various resources for GUI programming. The Apple's Cocoa documentation, even not related to web is very good and exhaustive resource on the topic with information on various techniques and their advantages.

You can look into EmberJS architecture as well. They have borrowed a lot from Cocoa.

This talk from Yehuda Katz is pretty useful about different UI approaches in the web and what is required for a good UI, what are the technical problems everyone has to face - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s1dhXamEAKQ.

Another interesting approach is what Facebook's React frameworks is doing. They advertise themselves by the lack of bi-directional bindings and their approach is very good actually.